# Combination of Echo and >> operator command

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I was learning how to configure Django on OpenShift and got stuck with following commands.

Can anyone help me to find out what operation is performed by these commands here and what can be its equivalent if I want to implement the same on windows command prompt.

```
Configure a few environmental variables to make your workflow easier

cd ~/app-root/data/django/wsgi/openshift
echo "cd ~/app-root/data" >> ~/app-root/data/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first command just changes directory - the `~` means "relative to the home directory."

The Windows equivalent would be to reference the home directory environment variable:

```
cd %USERPROFILE%\app-root\data\django\wsgi\openshift
```

The second command adds the command `cd ~/app-root/data` to the bash profile, which is executed at login time.  This doesn't have a direct equivalent in Windows because you log into a gui.  I doubt it matters much, it is a convenience, and you can just change to the directory you want when opening a cmd window.

Comment: But if echo adds it then it would be somthing like "cd /home/app-root/data/.bash_profile/home/app-root/data" ? Is this correct ? Little confused here.

Comment: No, echo on its own just prints what is in between the quotes.  The `>>` means "add whatever came out of the previous command to the end of this file".  So it is the `.bash_profile` file that has the `cd` command added to the end of it, and just the cd command as it is written between the quotes